# Styled Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm able to style a map perfectly so that it is desaturated. I am also able to style the map so that it has a custom marker. However i cannot combine the code to make a desaturated map with a custom marker. Could someone please take a look at my script and check that i have the right bits in the right place. Thanks for your help guys - hugely appreciated:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(53.798709, -1.550740); 

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.798709, -1.550740),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);

var image = 'images/marker.png';
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.798709, -1.550740);
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: image
});

var featureOpts = [
{
  stylers: [

    ]
},{
        featureType: "all",

        stylers: [{
            saturation: -100
        }]},

   {

    }]

    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Your "script" is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to apply the style.

Put this line to the end of `initialize()`:

```
map.setOptions({styles:featureOpts});
```

Or define the styles with the `mapOptions`:

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom:       14,
  center:     new google.maps.LatLng(53.798709, -1.550740),
  mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles:     [
                {
                  featureType: "all",
                  stylers: [
                            {
                              saturation: -100
                            }
                           ]
                }
              ]
};
```